# Change accepted answer of my question if a better one appears

Tags: support, accepted-answer

The title pretty much sums it up. Should I change the accepted answer of my question if someone answers the question "better" or more extensively? Even though the accepted answer is right?

Answer (score 7):

Well, technically you're *allowed* to accept any answer to your question that you want, and to change which answer is accepted as often as the system allows you to.

If you want to be a "good Stack Exchange citizen", you should be reasonably sure that the answer you accept is *correct*. Sometimes there are multiple correct answers. Which one you choose to accept is up to you; you might choose the clearest one, or the most complete one, or the most technically correct one, or the one that most closely matches what you asked, or whatever. So, yes you can unaccept an existing answer and accept a new one if you think the new answer deserves it more. But you don't have to. It's your call.

By the way, as a corollary to this, if you want to be a good SE citizen you should not accept an answer without being reasonably confident that it's correct. Sometimes that means you don't accept an answer at all, which is fine, e.g. if none of the answers seem to be correct or even if they might be correct but you are not reasonably confident in that.

Comment: Alright, that seems more or less what I am following. I guess I should have phrased my question as "Should the accepted answer be also the best of the answers?", but I guess as you put it, it's up to me

Comment: Yeah, it's up to you... but I suppose there is something to be said for making sure the best answer is the accepted one. I personaly would not hesitate to unaccept an answer and accept another one if I thought the new answer were better. The acceptance checkmark is supposed to indicate something like "If you only read one answer to this question, make it this one".

Comment: Ok, it's noted !

Comment: Very good answer. I would add that in general it is advisable to wait a day or two before accepting any answer at all. That way you are more likely to get several different answers from which you can choose the one you like the most and accept it (or not, if you dont like any of them).